# Finding matching objects in Java

Tags: java, matching, hashset, treemap

I'm currently trying to match 2 objects based on their values. Except, it's not `a.a = a.a`, but `a.a = a.b` and `a.b = b.a`. This means that overriding `equals` is an option but it's certainly not the right option.

While sorting these objects will make the matching time quicker, the population will be small so it is unnecessary. Also, `compareTo` isn't exactly right either for the same reason given for `equals`.

Do I simply make my own method in case? There will be 4 fields to match which is why I am not using an if statement up front.

```
public boolean isOpposite(Object other) {
    return (this.a == other.b) ? true : false;
}
```

There is also the possibility that the object will implement/extend a base object to take on more fields and implement its own way of matching.

I'm considering using a `LinkedList` because I know it to be quicker for use than `ArrayList`, however I've also been considering `Map`s.
Edit: better explanation of objects

```
    public class Obj {     
public String a;     
public String b;     
public String c;     
public double d;    
}
```

The relationships are as follows:

```
    Obj obj1, obj2;
obj1.a == obj2.b //.equals for String of course
obj1.b == obj2.a
obj1.c == obj2.c
obj1.d == obj2.d * -1
```

Comment: Why do you think a `LinkedList` would be faster when access time is O(n) (amortized)?

Comment: There would be constant accessing to the objects in the list. I was informed by another person LinkedLists are quicker at this. Was I informed wrongly?

Comment: Can you explain the equivalence relation for this class in more concrete terms (i.e. what are the 4 relevant class members, and what defines equality wrt those members)?

Comment: If you're only getting things from the front or the back, then yes - it's constant time.  If you're getting things from the middle, then it has to traverse at most N/2 elements to find it.  An `ArrayList` is faster since it supports random access (backed by an array).

Comment: @Makoto thank you for that distinction. I understand now.

Comment: @tavnab of say N variables, some would br equivalent while some would be opposite, and some may be irrelevant for comparison purposes.

Comment: Could you define some equivalencies?  Is it symmetric?  (`a.a = a.b <=> a.b = a.a`)?   Commutative?

Comment: For clarity sake, please refer to the 2 objects being compared as `obj1` and `obj2`. You mentioned four members in your question; let's call them `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`. Please define equivalence in these terms.

Comment: I can't seem to enter a line break on my phone. I will update the main post with a better description. Thank you for your time and patience,

Comment: Some of the "relationships" you've added to your question make no sense. For example, "obj1.a != obj1.a" can never be true. Please fix this. Also, are your requiring that every listed relationship be true in order to find a "match"?

Comment: @cybersam hi, I've removed those two lines. No idea what I was thinking. The other 4 relationships were correctly defined.

Comment: OK, I assume that you want every listed relationship be true in order to find a "match". But you only state that you want to match objects; what are you trying to do with list(s) or map(s)? For example, do you want to compare two `Obj` lists, such that elements with the same index "match" according to your relationships?

Comment: @cybersam I see these objects arriving in a single list of List <Obj>. Because of the last variable, c, the double has a relationship of Obj1.c == Obj2.c * -1, I was thinking I could cut the matching time in half by pivoting on that field and creating 2 lists. Positive and negative. However I would still need to run through the 2nd list up to N times per object in the 1st list. So still N^2. After the pivot I could sort these lists before matching based on Obj.c which may or may not cut matching time considerably based on the other 3 semi-random fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some testing and determined that the cleanest way I knew how to implement this was with using `ArrayList<Obj>`.

This was my implementation:

```
public static List<ObjGroup> getNewSampleGroup(int size) {
    List<ObjGroup> sampleGroup = new ArrayList<ObjGroup>();
    sampleGroup.add(new ObjGroup((generateNumbers(size, 1)))); //Positives
    sampleGroup.add(new ObjGroup((generateNumbers(size, -1)))); //Negatives
    return sampleGroup;
}

private static List<Obj> generateNumbers(int size, int x) {
    List<Obj> sampleGroup = new ArrayList<Obj>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        String randC;
        String randA;
        String randB;
        double randD;

        if (x == 1) {
            randD = rand.nextInt((maxP - minP + 1) + minP);
            randA = "aval";// + String.valueOf(rand.nextInt((max - min + 1) + min));
            randB = "bval";// + String.valueOf(rand.nextInt((max - min + 1) + min));
            randC = "cval";// + String.valueOf(rand.nextInt((max - min + 1) + min));
        } else {
            randD = rand.nextInt((maxP - minP + 1) + minP) * -1;
            randA = "bval";// + String.valueOf(rand.nextInt((max - min + 1) + min));
            randB = "aval";// + String.valueOf(rand.nextInt((max - min + 1) + min));
            randC = "cval";// + String.valueOf(rand.nextInt((max - min + 1) + min));
        }
        sampleGroup.add(new Obj(randA, randB, randC, randD));
    }
    return sampleGroup;
}

public List<ObjGroup> findMatches(List<ObjGroup> unmatchedList) {
    List<Obj> pivotPos = unmatchedList.get(0).getObjs(); //First grouping are positives
    List<Obj> pivotNeg = unmatchedList.get(1).getObjs(); //Second grouping are negatives
    List<ObjGroup> matchedList = new ArrayList<ObjGroup>();
    long iterations = 0;

    Collections.sort(pivotPos);
    Collections.sort(pivotNeg, Collections.reverseOrder());

    for (Iterator<Obj> iteratorPos = pivotPos.iterator(); iteratorPos.hasNext();) {
        final Obj focus = iteratorPos.next();
        iteratorPos.remove(); //Remove this once pulled as you won't match it again.
        for (Iterator<Obj> iteratorNeg = pivotNeg.iterator(); iteratorNeg.hasNext();) {
            final Obj candidate = iteratorNeg.next();
            if (compare(focus, candidate)) {
                matchedList.add(new ObjGroup(new ArrayList<Obj>() {
                    {
                        add(focus);
                        add(candidate);
                    }
                }));
                iteratorNeg.remove(); //Remove this once matched as you won't match it again.
                break;
            }
            iterations ++;
        }
        iterations ++;
    }
    return matchedList;
}
```

I ran this against a sample size of 4,000,000 psuedo random `Obj` objects. This was my output:

```
Starting matching test.
18481512007 iterations.
3979042 matched objects.
10479 unmatched objects.
Processing time: 44 minutes.
There were 1989521 number of matches found.
Closing matching test.
```

Answer (score 2):

Overriding the `equals` or `compareTo` is not the right way to go, as you've mentioned. Because there is an assumption that both methods should be transitive, i.e. `A eq B and B eq C => A eq C` but it doesn't hold for the "opposite" objects. It's good to know, because you can't define a equivalence class and partition it into subsets, but you need to find all the pairs (depending on your use case).

Not sure, what is your goal. If you have some containers with such objects and you need to find all pairs that suffice the condition, then I am afraid you'd need to do n^2 comparisons.

I'll probably create two hash sets, one with the originals and second with the opposites and ask if the second hash set contains the opposite of each member of original hash set.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jiri,
Yeah, the N^2 comparison is not something I'm looking forward to. With ~40,000 entries, N^2 is looking at an average of 100,000,000 iterations after sorting by the pivot and breaking into 2 Lists. I'm going to give HashSets a try and reply my findings once done. Thank again,